# parse hidden data from web page using ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing

Example: "https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/ETHUSD/technicals/" shows price (under "Market Open"). This price visible in .inspect code for this element:
680.34
but hidden in "view source". 
All known for me parsing (like Nokogiri) find that element empty, analysing html from "view source". Certainly this price comes as result of server script after page loaded.
Any ways to get this price using ruby (may be nokogiri, mechanize)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Capybara+ChromeHeadless to parse the page with JS: 
https://drivy.engineering/running-capybara-headless-chrome/

But If you only need the exchange rate of currency, I strongly believe there are open sources for that, so parsing page looks overcomplicated to me https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38309/what-are-the-popular-api-to-get-current-exchange-rates-for-ethereum-to-usd

Comment: Thanks for response. I would like to get reliable data at least to check or modify technical analysis given at this site. Moreover, this site data very close to binance data that is interesting for me.